# Im facing error in reset method in reactjs. How can i use that method according to my coding in react

Tags: reactjs

Here i have my codesandbox link. https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-hamilton-elg9i9?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js Here how can i use my  reset method for clearing all details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should import useForm like this in curly brackets

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: i think it is your code error, not an importing or any other error

Comment: please read the react useForm docs so you can understand it